# Graying out a specific date with jQuery UI doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, frontend

With the code below, I'm trying to gray out 21/12/2020 because we don't ship until Tuesday(22/12/2020). I cannot find what is wrong in the code below. Please point out the error in the code that might be causing it not to work.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        jQuery(function() {
            jQuery("#ship_date").datepicker( {
            var minDate;
                // get current date
                var d = new Date();
                var month = d.getMonth()+1;
                var day = d.getDate();
                var current_date = (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day + d.getFullYear() + '/'; 
    
                if (current_date < new Date(11, 22, 2020) {
                    minDate = new Date( 11, 22, 2020 );
                } else {
                    minDate = +1;
                }
                maxDate: '+2M',
                beforeShowDay: jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends
            } );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED the answer as per request from PKTG:

```
<script>
      $( function() {
        var cuttoffdate = new Date(2020,11, 22);
        $( "#ship_date" ).datepicker(
        {
                    maxDate: '+2M',
                     beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                        show = true;
                        if (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6) { show = false; }
                        if(date<cuttoffdate) { show=false;};
                        var display = [show, '', (show) ? '' : 'Not available'];
                        return display;
                    }
                }
        );
      } );

</script>
```

Comment: looking at my code, this could be made a little better by adding a break; in the loop when it finds the date, also not checking the holidays if it is a weekend (in my case I want to)  - maybe using a hashset or something to determine the date ??, but this is to show the "principle" of how to do it ..

Comment: Thanks Anton. Can you please tell if one can use comparison operator with the dates as did I here if `(current_date <  exlude_date)` ?

Comment: you must remember dates are a very complicated thing - especially in browsers and because we are all over the world (something you have to consider is different time zones, things like daylight savings etc) .. so that said, I have used "moment.js" for all / most of my dates in websites and to work with them properly - converting all dates to UTC and then work with them ..  and yes one can then have comparison operations available .. see : https://momentjs.com/

Comment: an example .. someone in new zealand will have 1st of January BEFORE someone in England ... and then in England they sometimes have daylight saving, changing things by an hour ..

Comment: Yes, I understand. I'm looking to see if my code can be made to work. Kindly see if there is a way.

Comment: @PKTG - I updated the answer - your problem was your date was in wrong format - new Date(year, month-1, day) ..

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working although I didn't understand the code very well.

Comment: var cuttoffdate = new Date(2020,11, 22);   - sets the date to 2020-12-22 (months are 0 based (jan =0, dec =11),  
then the API doc is here : https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay
you will see it says - A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array   ... 
so in the code it returns "display", which is the array - you can play with the style sheet and optional tooltip message - hope this helps a little in understanding what is going on .

Comment: this part : if (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6) { show = false; } - is the weekends -- Sunday ==0 and Saturday == 6 - so it excludes the Sunday and Saturday .

Comment: Everything except for var display = [show, '', (show) ? '' : 'Not available']; is clear. Please tell what is happening here.

Comment: var display - is an array - and show is a boolean - the "? is a ternary operator .. in form 
(check condition) ? value if true : value if false - same as saying if(check condition) then { do this when true} else {do this when false } - so the code says if (show==true) then { make the value "" } else { make the value "Not available" }
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Which means the array display would finally have 2 elements show and empty string. Am I correct?

Comment: 3 elements -  either  for false case : [false, "" , "Not available" ]  or [true, "", ""]

Comment: I thought the value of show element will be replaced by either "" value or Not available value by the ternary operator.

Comment: another thing that might be confusing : the function beforeShowDay - is called for every date that the control wants to display - so for each date in the "calendar" if will call this and then check the date .. and based on the true or false display that date .. does that help?

Comment: maybe this will make more sense : the beforeShowDay CAN be re-written as 

beforeShowDay: function (date) {
 show = true;
 if (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6) { 
  show = false; 
 }
 else if( date < cuttoffdate) { 
  show = false;
 };
 
 if(show) { 
  return [ true, "", "" ];
 }
 else {
  return [ false, "", "Not Available" ];
 }
}

Comment: i simplified it even more for your understanding - the formatting doesn't work here:
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
 if (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6) { 
  return [ false, "", "A weekend day" ];
 };
 if( date < cuttoffdate) { 
  return [ false, "", "Before cuttoffdate" ];
 };
 return [ true, "", "" ];
}

Comment: All clear, grateful for your sincere efforts to educate me on this. It means a lot Anton.

Comment: I don't know if I can ask for your skype ID or email but I would love to have it, never to disturb you now and then. Will be in touch with you whenever I can.